What bandwidth value is LTspice reporting in the waveform viewer when Ctrl-click the data trace label?
When performing an AC analysis and Ctrl-clicking the data trace label in the waveform viewer, LTspice reports BW and Power BW in a pop-up window. What actually are those measurements? None of them seem to be the -3 dB bandwidth. See the example below.


Maybe you should not obscure the cursor 2 data as it might be the clue you need.

Only one cursor is active and it shows the -3dB point.

Could it be the 0.1 dB flatness bandwidth, maybe?

Both BW and Power BW are above the -3dB point.

BW and Power BW seem to be calculated similarly to average and RMS values i.e. by integrating voltage over frequency. It is not resembling what you would consider bandwidth in the first place. It appears to come from noise analysis in LTspice and calculation of equivalent noise bandwidth (ENBW). You can read more about it at LTspice@groups.io

Thanks, just the answer I was looking for! So, basically useless measurements that could almost be considered as a bug.

@FreddaH  Sounds like it's useful for noise analysis, though.

Only if you're actually doing a noise analysis (.NOISE) and in that case you're getting an anser like: Total RMS noise: 356.34uV. For an AC analysis it's only confusing and more or less useless.
